# Sorting boolean arrays by number of *true* values in Java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

(I work in processing 3.3.5)

My code generates many boolean arrays of the same length ( 8 ).
After some manipulation, I want to sort these arrays by the number of "true" values. I use boolean arrays for convenience; feel free to think about them like 8 bit numbers and sorting them by number of set bits. Also no duplicates allowed.

Eventually I want to display these arrays in the following manner:

All arrays with a single true value: Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4 ...

All arrays with two true values: Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4 ...

All arrays with three true values: Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4 ...

All arrays with four true values: Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4 ...

...

....

The (non-working) way I do it right now, is by having a 3D boolean Array (let us say you get to a specific index - in the boolean Arrays I want to sort - by the coordinates [x][y][z])

x are columns, y are rows, z are indecies of the *.length 8* boolean arrays

(0. Check if the array I want to sort right now has a duplicate already)

1. Get number of true values (y position)
2. Go through x positions:
3. Check if [x][y][0 through 7] is empty, if true: write array in those positions. (if not: go to next x position)

(I do this with 2 funtions: hasEqual and findEmpty, if you are interested in unannotated code... here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83fa90fdaacbeffb8ecc3d5c5a513890 (prepare for cringe))

Any help would be much appreciated! **Can be pseudo code, or just ideas/concepts!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that easily by utilizing the Stream API's `sorted()` method in conjunction with `Comparator.comparing(arr -> getNumberOfTrueValues(arr))`

Comment: Thanks, I got stuff to google now, to find out about streams.